# Google calendar api 3 invalid credentials error

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to access calendar details but I seem to get a invalid credentials error.
I access the following url: "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{google_id}/events"

like this :

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url_); 
get.addHeader("Authorization","OAuth" + auth_token);
try {
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
```

What extra headers should I put there? I'm accessing it from an android application. If it matters I got my auth_token by an activity started with AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent().

I'm getting the following json:

```
{
  "error": {
   "errors": [
    {
     "domain": "global",
     "reason": "authError",
     "message": "Invalid Credentials",
     "locationType": "header",
     "location": "Authorization"
    }
   ],
   "code": 401,
   "message": "Invalid Credentials"
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be a space between OAuth and the token in your header.